# How to capture the video frames from the decoder while Playing a Youtube movie on Android 4.4?

Tags: android, video, youtube, video-capture, v4l2

I need to get the youtube movie while it's played frame by frame, as they are drawn to the screen.
Is there a way using v4l2 / /dev/ion or something else, to get the frames as they are displayed?

I know, there is the new screenrecord binary. But I don't want to record the screen, just get the movie frames ( best in full res ) while they are displayed - independent of the displayed movie size. Detecting rebuffering is important too. No frame should be returned during a freezing, not a rotating circle.
Thanks a lot for any hints!

Comment: You want to ripp off youtube videos as they are streamed? Not sure it's allowed.

Comment: It's not to rip the video. Just image quality tests on the frames. They are discarded again immediately.

Comment: And how does it streams? From where? Show use some code.

Comment: Just play any Youtube video.

Comment: From what app? Using what code? Explain more or we can't do much, can we?

Comment: How can I somehow add a second client to the V4L2 system, which gets the frames simultaneous as the display.

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421958/get-all-0-data-when-capture-video-using-v4l2-on-android