# Difference between error function and printf function

Tags: c

First of all, sorry if someone already asked about this question.

I did search about this first, but couldn't find one.

I used to see some people doing something like this:

```
if ( // a certain conditions here ) {
    error("ERROR: not bla bla bla")
}
```

what is `error(....)`? What is the difference with `printf()`?

Why they aren't using `printf("ERROR: not bla bla bla")` instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know, c language has no function name "error". I think that is a function or a macro is coded or defined by user.
To handle error in c, you can read this link. It has some different points with printf function.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_error_handling.htm

Comment: Good idea. Yeah I think that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), which includes `stdin` (for input), `stdout` for output, and `stderr` for error messages. Usually `stdout` and `stderr` are just terminal output, so there are no differences. However, the output can be redirected to a text file while all error messages are still available output.

Also have look at this question [`perror` vs `frintf(stderr..)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102332/when-i-should-use-perror-and-fprintfstderr), which gives you a better idea as to why `perror` should be used.